# Prettier and EsLint Tab Problem - curiouse sign in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, prettier

I have a little problem with Prettier my code in .vue.
From some time, when I save my files I get problem like this:

[Code and problems screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPSW6.png)

This is my .prettierrc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: true,
  trailingComma: "es5",
  tabWidth: 2,
  semi: false,
  singleQuote: false,
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow prettier is using tabs to format your code, this is not happening frequently?

It looks you have an eslint or some sort of linting rule running in vscode that is expecting the format to use spaces and not tabs.

Are you sure you don't have any other prettier configuration with `useTabs` prettier flag set to true?

Comment: Thanks for yout help.
I add: useTabs: true, to .prettuerrc.js file and now all is ok.
Cheers